# ArgumentOutOfRangeException while calling FAST-Search service

Tags: web-services, fast-search

I am getting an exception:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: FaultException 
Exception message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

while calling my FS4SP web service. It runs fine for small queries but fails when my search criteria becomes large (2000+ characters). Does FS4SP has a limitation on search criteria? My QueryText in in STRING format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen, the limit for the Query is actually 2048 characters. So any more than that will throw this exception.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061330/how-to-overcome-fast-search-char-limitation-2048 is a possible duplicate of your question, but sadly it never recieved any attention.

Also this from Technet http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fastsharepoint/thread/b193fc10-3c39-43d3-9e4a-378ff90125f2 with some answers and approaches